# Is there a way to erase two given values with loop?

Tags: c++

How do I erase if string sdl1 holds two values like "37". Considering that are two different values 3 and 7. Do I need some sort of list or only loop? Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iterator>


using namespace std;



void eraseAllSubStr(std::string & mainStr, const std::string & toErase)
{
    size_t pos = std::string::npos;

    while ((pos = mainStr.find(toErase)) != std::string::npos)
    {


            mainStr.erase(pos, toErase.length());

    }
}


int main()
{
    std::string str = "123456789";
    //Let's Say I want to delete 5 and 8 and string sdl1 = "58".
    string sdl1 = "5";
    eraseAllSubStr(str, sdl1);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the minimal reprod. example:

```
12346789
5 was erased.
But I would like to erase two values like 5 and 8 where string sdl1 = "58"
```

Comment: You really didn't need to post all of that code to figure out how to delete multiple numbers from a vector.  As a matter of fact, you should have taken a step back and write a very simple `main` with a vector of numbers/digits you want to delete, and then try to delete them.  Then when you know how to do that, *then* you apply what you learned into the larger program.  Instead you have one big program full of things that are irrelevant to the issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: Also, your output suggests that you are not adjusting the index when an item is deleted.  If you delete a digit, then all of the indices of the elements after the deletion are reduced by one.  Thus `9` is no longer at index 3 after you deleted `8`.  If you drew this out on paper, you should have realized this.

Comment: Actually I don't delete by index, but by value.

Comment: Deletion for the container(s) you're using require an iterator.  That iterator is basically an index.

Comment: Could you please guide me on how to adjust the index after erasing? I tried other method and it gives error "out of range".. Thank you

Comment: *Actually I don't delete by index, but by value* -- Then whittle your code down to a [mcve], where you declared a vector (or string), and attempt to do this deletion by value.  [Start with this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbe344c5174bd4f8)

Comment: I edited my code to  minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hey, I seem to be late to the party. This seems to work now. The point of reproducing is that it produces the error.

Comment: this works if you erase "5", then erase "8", and are left with "1234679" That's what you said you wanted. Not clicking external link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your actual question:

> *"What If I want to remove "58" like 5 and 8?"*

and you want to provide `std::string sdl1 = "58";` and have both `5` and `8` removed from `std::string str = "123456789";` in a single loop, then you can simply use [std::basic_string::find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) to locate the position of either `5` or `8` and then use [std::basic_string::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) to remove the character. The only constraint is you only want to attempt the removal of characters while `str.find_first_of (sdl1) != std::basic::npos)`.

A `for` loop is tailor made for the implementation, e.g.:

```
    std::string str = "123456789";
    //Let's Say I want to delete 5 and 8 and string sdl1 = "58".
    std::string sdl1 = "58";

    for (size_t pos = str.find_first_of (sdl1);
                pos != std::string::npos;
                pos = str.find_first_of (sdl1))
        str.erase (pos, 1);
```

Putting it altogether in a short example, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (void) {

    std::string str = "123456789";
    //Let's Say I want to delete 5 and 8 and string sdl1 = "58".
    std::string sdl1 = "58";

    for (size_t pos = str.find_first_of (sdl1);
                pos != std::string::npos;
                pos = str.find_first_of (sdl1))
        str.erase (pos, 1);

    std::cout << "str: " << str << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/erasechars
str: 1234679
```

Comment: It does what I wanted. You made easy to understand. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

## Erase as substring

If you want to erase as a substring, the code you wrote is solution to your problem. Run again your code by putting

```cpp
std::string str = "123456789";
string sdl1 = "56";
```

You will get your ouput `1234789`.

Once again set the inputs

```cpp
std::string str = "12345678956123";
string sdl1 = "56";
```

You will get your output `1234789123`

So you've successfully removed all the occurrences of `56` from your main string `str`.

The way `std::string::find()` works, it searches the string for the first occurrence of the sequence specified by its arguments. So it will work same for a substring as it works for a single character.

Similarly `std::string::erase()` erases a part of the string, reducing its length. All you need is to specify the starting index and the length of the substring (i.e. `string ::erase (size_type idx, size_type len )`) you would like to remove.

So, your code will work for removing all the occurrences of a given substring.

## Erase as character

If you want to remove one or more characters from a string like you mentioned `5` and `8`. You can use your code with simple modification to your `eraseAllSubStr` function.

```cpp
void eraseAllSubStr(std::string & mainStr, const std::string & toErase)
{
    size_t pos = std::string::npos;

    // erase all the occurrences of the characters that are
    // given through toErase string 
    // and obviously the length of a char is 1  
    for( int id = 0; id < toErase.size(); id++)
    { 
       while ((pos = mainStr.find(toErase[id])) != std::string::npos)
       {
           mainStr.erase(pos,1);
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: What If I want to remove "58" like 5 and 8?

Comment: @user10049461 Can you make sure that whether you want to remove all `58` where they are adjacent or want to remove all '5' and all '8' no matter what the order is?

Comment: the order doesn't matter, as long as it removes the given values. Your code code does what I was looking for. Thank you